# update MySQL resultset through user-interaction and make the changes global for the application

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I fetching a result set from a MySQL table and displaying it on the web page as under:

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect(....);
  mysql_select_db(....);

  $sql = "select * from products where category = '" .$_POST['prod_cat']. "'";
  $rs  = mysql_query($sql, $link);

  echo "<form name='prodselect' action='prodlist.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<table>";
  $rowcount = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['product_name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='line_" .$rowcount. "'></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</form>";
?>
```

This displays the list of products with checkbox for every product row.
The user will select products using the checkboxes.

I want to display / save the selected products in the "Products for Purchase" list on another web page.

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to create the checkbox like this:

```
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='" .$row['product_id']. "'></td>";
```

then on the `prodlist.php` you can get the array `$_POST['products']`